# Как изменить размер окружности, которая нарисована на canvas'е? (Paper.js)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Ниже приведён код, с помощью которого на canvas'е можно нарисовать окружность (нажимаем ЛКМ, двигаем мышкой и отпускаем). Как можно заметить, на окружности есть красная точка (на самом деле это маленькая окружность).

Собственно проблема: нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии и удерживании ЛКМ на этой красной точке и движение мышкой, окружность изменяла свой размер (центр окружности оставался бы прежним, а радиус становился бы расстоянием от центра до нового положения курсора). После того, как мы отпустим ЛКМ, окружность перестаёт изменять свой размер.

Выше описанную процедуру можно повторять сколько угодно раз.

Ниже в коде написан комментарий, где, по моему мнению, нужно писать код.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="geometry.css">
    <title>Paper.js</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="paper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="geometry.js"></script>


    <a href="#" id="handID">Hand</a>
    <a href="#" id="circleID">Circle</a>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    paper.install(window);
    paper.setup("myCanvas");

    //получаем все инструменты по id, чтобы повесить на них прослушку
    var handToolActive = document.getElementById("handID");
    var circleToolActive = document.getElementById("circleID");

    //создаём инструменты
    var handTool = new Tool();
    var circleTool = new Tool();

    //функции для изменения размера окружности
    handToolActive.onclick = function () {
        handTool.activate();
        var items = project.getItems({class: Shape }); //здесь сохранены все объекты, которые находятся на канвасе

        handTool.onMouseDown = function (event) {
            event_x = event['point']['x'];
            event_y = event['point']['y'];

            //Вот здесь у меня не получается написать код
        };
    };

    //функции для создания окружности 
    circleToolActive.onclick = function () {
        circleTool.activate();

        var circle; //окружность
        var centreDotOfCircle; //центр окружности
        var radiusOfCircle; //радиус окружности
        var outsideDotOfCircle; //точка, которая лежит на окружности (её мы и двигаем, чтобы изменить размеры окружности)

        circleTool.minDistance = 0;
        circleTool.onMouseDown = function(event) {
            radiusOfCircle = 0;
            circle = new paper.Shape.Circle(event.point, 0);
            circle.strokeWidth = 2;
            circle.strokeColor = '#222222';

            centreDotOfCircle = new paper.Shape.Circle(event.point, 4);
            centreDotOfCircle.strokeWidth = 2;
            centreDotOfCircle.fillColor = '#fafafa';
            centreDotOfCircle.strokeColor = '#ff333a';

            outsideDotOfCircle = new paper.Shape.Circle(event.point, 4);
            outsideDotOfCircle.strokeWidth = 2;
            outsideDotOfCircle.fillColor = '#fafafa';
            outsideDotOfCircle.strokeColor = '#ff333a';
        };

        circleTool.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
            radiusOfCircle = event.point - circle.position;
            radiusOfCircle = Math.sqrt((event.point.x - circle.position.x) ** 2 + (event.point.y - circle.position.y) ** 2); //выщитываем радиус по теореме Пифагора

            if (radiusOfCircle > 15) { //если радиус окружности меньше 15 - то делаем радиус окружности 0
                circle.radius = radiusOfCircle;
                outsideDotOfCircle.position = event.point;
            } else {
                radiusOfCircle = 0;
                circle.radius = 0;
                outsideDotOfCircle.position = centreDotOfCircle.position;
            }
        };
        circleTool.onMouseUp = function(event) { //если у окружности радиус 0 - удаляем её 
            if (radiusOfCircle === 0) {
                circle.remove();
                centreDotOfCircle.remove();
                outsideDotOfCircle.remove();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

ссылка на paper.js: [официальный сайт](http://paperjs.org/download/)